# How to remove ajax appended container with data-id

Tags: jquery

I am adding a hidden fields with user selection so I can reinsert them later. Also I am adding a normal div, to show the user their selection.

I am trying to create a delete function, where the button will delete the visible row, as well as the hidden one.

Right now I am able to delete the correct visible row, but it won't delete the correct hidden div.

I have tried to get the `data-id`, but it always deletes the last one in the row, not the corresponding one.

How can I delete the correct div from `#hiddenChildAgeRanges` that corresponds to the one in `#visibleAgeRange`?

```
  //nanny childcare ranges
        $.each(data.nanny_age_range, function(index, data) {   

                var str = '<a href="#" id="' + data.nanny_age_range_id + '" aria-label="Close" class="deleteAge"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';

                var hiddenAgeTo = '<input id="userProfileAgeTo' + childAgeCount + '" value="'+data.age_maximum+'" name="userProfileAgeTo[]" style="visibility:hidden; position:absolute;" type="text" />';

                var hiddenAgeFrom = '<input id="userProfileAgeFrom' + childAgeCount + '" value="'+data.age_minimum+'" name="userProfileAgeFrom[]" style="visibility:hidden; position:absolute;" type="text" />';

                var childAgeAppend = 
                    '   <div class="col-md-12" id="childAgeRange'+childAgeCount+'">'+
                    '       <div class="col-md-3">'+
                    '       <b>From'+data.age_minimum+' to '+data.age_maximum+'</b>'+
                    '       </div>'+
                    '       <div class="col-md-3">'+
                    '       '+str+''+
                    '       </div>'+
                    '</div>';
                $("#hiddenChildAgeRanges").append('<div name="nanny_age_range_id[]" value="'+data.nanny_age_range_id+'" id="userAgeRangeSelection'+ childAgeCount+'" data-id="userAgeRangeSelection'+data.nanny_age_range_id+'">'+ hiddenAgeFrom + hiddenAgeTo+'');
                $("#visibleAgeRange").append(childAgeAppend);
                childAgeCount++;   

        });

//delete nanny age range
$(document).on("click", ".deleteAge", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var age_id = $(this).attr('id');

    $(this).closest('.col-md-12').fadeOut(300, function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'PHP/deleteData.php',
        data: "age_id=" + age_id,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                childAgeCount--;
            } else if (data.status == 'error') {
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data) {
            console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are creating the hidden element using the `nanny_age_range_id` property which is also the ID attribute of `deleteAge` element. Create the selector and do the operation.

You can use [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and the `remove()`.

```
//delete nanny age range
$(document).on("click", ".deleteAge", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var age_id = $(this).attr('id');

    $('[data-id="userAgeRangeSelection' + age_id +'"]').remove();
    //Rest of the code
});
```